Handling a comma inside a cookie value using C# and .NET 6
I encountered an issue while trying to read the content of a third-party cookie.
The cookie contains values like: 110, IN, ABC, X, Y,,,,,
I'm reading the cookie using:
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["key"];

But it did not return all the data.
Note: this is third-party cookie and I can not encode it to get rid of it.

It occurs to me that you use a split but since you said that it is a third-party cookie, that wouldn't work, right?

Yes, I'm not getting the complete data on the backend.

But even if you don't get them, if you can confirm that they are all separated by commas with split, you can get all the values ​​using a foreach and store it in a list

I got a fix: instead of getting cookie value like
Get as below:
 private string ParseCookie(string cookieKey)
 {
    var cookieHeader = 
    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"].ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieHeader))
    {
       // Split the cookies by ';' which is the delimiter for multiple cookies
       var cookies = cookieHeader.Split(';');
       foreach (var cookie in cookies)
       {
        // Split the individual cookie by '='
        var parts = cookie.Split('=');
        if (parts.Length == 2)
        {
            var key = parts[0].Trim();
            var value = parts[1].Trim();

            if (key == cookieKey)
            {
                // Process the comma-separated value
                return Uri.UnescapeDataString(value);
                // Perform any necessary actions based on the cookie value
                break;
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return String.Empty;
}


In case you want to get the key values ​​and use or work with them he best way is to use split
var cookieValue = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["key"];
if (cookieValue != null)
{
    var values = cookieValue.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        // here you could save the values ​​in a list or work with them
    }
}

